Star delta connection blower motor
I have a star delta motor connection. I just want to confirm if the current from the motor going to the overload and contactor is the same as the contactor going to the breaker? Because the reading I got from the motor to the contactor in 11 A and the contactor going to the breaker in 18 A.

Welcome! Can you draw a block diagram or similar of how things are connected and exactly where you measured 11 A and 18 A respectively.

Here's the 'Star-Delta starter' schematic, courtesy theengineeringmindset.com.

When the line current through the circuit breaker 'Q1' is 18 A the current through the bimetal overload relay 'F1', being the phase current, is close to 11 A (18 / √ 3).

Thanks for the info

Anytime, Hisyam!
